# Django : Only display model items that match with for each category

Tags: python, django

Here are the models I've created

```
class Jeu(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField('Nom du jeu', max_length=100)
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True)


class Course(models.Model):
    jeu = models.ForeignKey(Jeu, verbose_name='Nom du jeu', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ligue = models.ForeignKey(Ligue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_evenement = models.DateTimeField("Date de la course")
```

Here is the view :

```
def home(request):
    courses_a_venir = Course.objects.filter(date_evenement__gte = datetime.today()).order_by('date_evenement')
    courses_passees = Course.objects.filter(date_evenement__lt = datetime.today()).order_by('-date_evenement')[:3]
    jeux = Jeu.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'base_site/home.html', context={'title': 'Accueil', 'courses_a_venir': courses_a_venir, 'jeux': jeux, 'courses_passees': courses_passees})
```

And then here is the HTML code :

```
{% for jeu in jeux %}
<h3>{{ jeu.nom }}</h3><br>
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
  {% for course in courses_a_venir %}
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <!--<img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">-->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ course.jeu }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
          content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">{{ course.date_evenement }}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div><br>
{% endfor %}
<br><br>
```

What I'd like to do, is to display only the "Course" items that match with the name of the "Jeu". I know that I have to insert an if statement in the HTML code, and I tried different things, such as :

```
    {% for jeu in jeux %}
      <h3>{{ jeu.nom }}</h3><br>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
      {% for course in courses_a_venir %}
      {% if course.jeu == jeu.nom %}
        .....
      {% endif %}
      .....
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

[The actual status of the HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpL86.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One robust way is to define those queries as model methods:

```
class Jeu(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField('Nom du jeu', max_length=100)
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def courses_a_venir():
        return self.course_set.filter(date_evenement__gte = datetime.today()).order_by('date_evenement')

    def courses_passees():
        return self.course_set.filter(date_evenement__lt = datetime.today()).order_by('-date_evenement')[:3]
```

You can then remove the context variables from your view:

```
def home(request):
    jeux = Jeu.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'base_site/home.html',
        context={'title': 'Accueil',  'jeux': jeux,}
    )
```

and simply do the following in your template:

```
{% for jeu in jeux %}
    <h3>{{ jeu.nom }}</h3><br>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    {% for course in jeu.courses_a_venir %}
        <p>{{ course.date_evenement }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It actually works now !
Just to understand.. what does "course_set" mean in these methods ?

Comment: It's a special suffix that lets you traverse ForeignKey relations in reverse. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ for details.

Comment: Just a quick update on that. I now have the list of all the "Course" that will happend, per "Jeu". The thing is some "Jeu" can contain multiple "Course", some none. But with how I created the HTLM template, I make a for loop before querying the "Course". So if there is a "Jeu" that doesn't contain any "Course", the category will still appear in the HTML page. Any way to display only the ones that contain at least one "Course" ?

Comment: Add another method (say, `has_courses`) and check the value of that using an `{% if %}` before you print a `Jeu`. I suggest you to post this as a new question if you need more clarification as a comment box is not the best place to answer it.

Comment: I posted the new question there. Thanks again ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996052/django-only-display-model-items-that-match-with-for-each-category-and-have-at/74996659#74996659